Refocus current window after new window loaded in JavaScript
I have a function that opens a pdf for the customer in another window:
const loadWindow = (windowFeatures: string, id: string, pdf: string): void => {
    evidenceWindow = pdf == File.MIME_TYPE ? window.open(
        `/transactions/matching_evidence/${id}#toolbar=0,view=FitH`,
        File.PDF,
        windowFeatures,
    ) : window.open(
        `/transactions/matching_evidence/${id}`,
        File.IMAGE,
        windowFeatures,
    )

    if (evidenceWindow !== null) {
        evidenceWindow.onload = () => {
            localStorage.setItem(GeneralLocalStorateItems.EVIDENCE_WINDOW_LOADED, "true")
            evidenceWindow!.onbeforeunload = () => {
                savePositionToStorage({ "top": evidenceWindow!.screenY, "left": evidenceWindow!.screenX, "height": evidenceWindow!.innerHeight, "width": evidenceWindow!.innerWidth })
                localStorage.setItem(GeneralLocalStorateItems.EVIDENCE_WINDOW_LOADED, "false")
            }
        }

        monitorWindow();
    }

}
Now I have a filter to filter invoices.
If this is happening, this function will be fired.
Then, the first invoice will be opened in a new window.
The problem that occurs is that the new Windows is now the focus.
I have 2 EventHandler to save the current active Element (since there are multiple ways to change the Invoice, not only by filtering) and refocus the element.
window.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    // Save the active element when the tab loses focus
    activeElement = document.activeElement as HTMLElement | null;
});


window.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    // Reapply focus to the saved active element when tab regains focus
    activeElement?.focus();
});

If I tab back into the Window, everything is fine and the correct Element is focused.
But I don't want the user to lose focus whenever they filter invoices.
So is there a way to re-focus the last window?
The browser would be Chrome.
Edit:
I have tried the suggestions already.
Also stuff like:
        if (evidenceWindow!.opener) {
            console.log("window:", window);
            console.log("evidenceWindow:", evidenceWindow!.opener);

            evidenceWindow!.opener.focus(); // Focus the parent window
            console.log("Opener window focused. Element: ", activeElement);
            activeElement?.focus();
            console.log("element focus setTimeout.");


        }

It seems there is no way to archive the behaviour I want?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus ?

https://dofollow.com/blog/noopener-noreferrer

Those both don't wark, sadly, but thanks anyway
